# Woocommerce API REST search by multiple keywords

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, api

0

I am working on a page for search Woocommerce products with the REST API. But I have a question about how I can search on keywords.

Product 1: Milkshake vanille / apple Product 2: Milkshake

If I use the keyword milkshake get both products if I search on milkshake vanille get only product 1.

I tried this: https://www.example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products?filter[s]={{milkshake, vanille}}';

But I get 10 product back also products without the right keywords.

Comment: It should be `?search=Milkshake+vanille`. You could check their rest api doc - https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#list-all-products

Comment: I tried this but I got 10 results back

Comment: Then other products description / short description contain those keywords.